# Максимальное количество сайтов которое можно разместить на сервере

Tags: сервер, администрирование, хостинг

**Имеется сервер со следующими характеристиками:**

Процессор: Intel Xeon E5-2430L v2, 2.8 Ghz Turbo, 6 ядер, 12 потоков

Оперативная память: 16гб

Пропускная способность: 1Gbps

Размер жёсткого диска: 1ТБ

**Вопрос:**

Сколько приблизительно сайтов-визиток(5-10 страниц) с ежедневной посещаемостью <= 100 человек сможет осилить данный сервер?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сложно сказать. Всё зависит от кучи факторов, не только от железа, но и от того как на чём будут сделаны сами страницы и какая технология размещения будет использована(классическое размещение через VirualHost, докер-контейнеры, etc). Но вообще -- много. А так -- надо тестить на небольшом количестве и дальше, по использованным ресурсам, посчитать на сколько ещё хватит. Естественно, что без системы мониторинга тут не обойтись, что-б понимать потребление ресурсов в течении времени, да и вообще полезно.